# Detect gesture on ExpansionTile's leading icon in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, gesture

How can I detect a gesture on the `ExpansionTile`'s leading widget in Flutter? I can't reliably make the leading icon trigger a function, instead what happens is that when I tap on the leading icon, the expansion tile just expands.

What I want is that when the user taps on the leading icon, the expansion tile does not change its state and the function I specified is called

I tried mixing `GestureDetector`, `IgnorePointer` but nothing worked so far.

```
  ExpansionTile(
    leading: GestureDetector(
      child: Icon(Icons.home),
      onTap: () {
        print('I want to execute something there...');
        print('and I also want to prevent toggling the expansion on the tile');
      },
    ),
    title: Text('Title'),
    children: [
      Text('child 1'),
      Text('child 2'),
    ],
    initiallyExpanded: true,
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `IconButton` instead of `Icon`, and implement your logic inside its `onPressed()` function:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final appTitle = 'ExpansionTile Issue';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
      body: Center(child: ExpansionTile(
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            onPressed: (){
              print('function is executed, but there is no expanstion triggering !');
            }
        ),

        title: Text('Title'),
            children: [
            Text('child 1'),
        Text('child 2'),
        ],
        initiallyExpanded: true,
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit:

After further investigating the issue, turned out there was nothing wrong with `GestureDetector`, it is just wrapping its child `Widget`, and it works fine when you use mouse clicks. But as fingers touch a much larger area, they trigger both the `GestureDetector` and its parent `ExpansionTile`.

One solution to this problem is to wrap your `leading` widget into a `Container` with larger width (say `width: 100.0`), so any actions away from its boundaries is certainly not intended for it:

```
GestureDetector(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            width: 80.0,
            height: 40.0,
            child: Icon(Icons.home),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            print('Now any click in this colored area will only trigger the GestureDetector, but make sure to set size depending on MediaQuery and textScaleFactor if you intend to use a Text Widget');
          },
        ),
```

Comment: And if my leading widget is not an Icon?